# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS on fedora

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, fedora

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I was wondering since there is no "official" way to installing hydro on fedora, would it be possible to install it from source ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143421/ros-on-fedora/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, there seem to be a few people using it on Fedora. I would go with the generic from-source install instructions. rosdep does support Fedora to install system dependencies: http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Source

People are working on a binary installer for Fedora, so it might soon be even easier than that: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/pull/228

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0